# Google Compute Engine Firewall Rule To Restrict Traffic O Certain Ports To Specific IP Addresses

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to restrict port access to certain IP addresses on Google Compute Engine. You are instructed to give ranges, but there are not examples shown how to limit access to just 3 IP addresses that are not in a range.

So for example, lets say I only want to allow these three ips:

```
22.22.22.22
44.44.44.44
77.77.77.77
```

How would I format my rule under the form field labeled `SOURCE IP RANGES`? Below are some things I tried but got errors on:

```
22.22.22.22,44.44.44.44,77.77.77.77
```

I tried with a range like this one, but it gave invalid address range

```
22.22.22.22/24,44.44.44.44/100,77.77.77.77/50
```

Comment: Network masks are expressed as a number of bits, starting at the left. IPv4 addresses are only 32 bits wide, so masks of 50 and 100 make no sense. An IP and a mask of 32 specify exactly one IP.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Thanks, I have no firewall experience.. I knew it was wrong, just did not know what was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're specified as CIDR addresses, meaning this:

> 22.22.22.22/32,44.44.44.44/32,77.77.77.77/32